# Is it possbile to update latext version to the latest version in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, latex

My operating system in Ubuntu 16.04 and the current version of latex is

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
```

Is it possible to upgrade it to the latest version (TeX Live 2019)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Answer (score 0):

You have to try famous [PPA of JonathonF](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive?field.series_filter=xenial) with TeXLive 2018:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # to get newest dependencies
```